# iOS - Set dashed line for a circle

Tags: ios, line

```
CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];

circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius) cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;

// Configure the apperence of the circle
circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
circle.lineWidth = 1;      
// Add to parent layer
[[background layer] addSublayer:circle];
```

I have drawn a circle and added it as a sublayer. What I don't understand is how to  make the circle line dashed? I have added my circle code above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the [`lineDashPattern` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008314-CH1-SW10) of `circle`.  For example:

```
circle.lineDashPattern = @[@2, @3];
```